# ComboBox IsEnabled property not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, isenabled

I am trying to disable items in a ComboBox when multiple properties (or'd together) result in false. The first time I click the ComboBox, the properties' getters are called and the correct state is shown. Every time I click the ComboBox after the  first, the properties are not checked again, even after they have been changed (meaning items enabled/disable state should be different).

Here is my code for the ComboBox item IsEnabled property:

```
<!--ItemContainer Style for disabling Combobox Item-->
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource orConverterKkey}">
                            <!--<Binding  Source="{StaticResource vm}" Path="NotUseAngleRange" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>-->
                            <Binding  Path="IsAxisEnabled" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                            <Binding  Source="{StaticResource vm}" Path="IsFull180AngleRange" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

My view model and combo box items implement `ViewModelBase` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class ViewModelReferenceAxisType : ViewModelBase
{
    public class ReferenceAxisTypeItem : ViewModelBase
    {
    ...
    }
}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
```

Comment: Did you implement Inotifypropertychanged in your model..

Comment: show us vm code when props change

Comment: I updated the question with the view model code, which shows where I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Maybe set Mode=TwoWay?